# number the soil_unit_code in a soil_id column

Tags: qgis, iteration, unique-value, column

I believe its pretty easy to be done, but I just don't seem to see the solution in Qgis. Is it possible in the field calculator?

I've an attributetable with 200 features with like 20 different `soil_unit_code` category's (aVz, EZ50A, Ezg21, etc). Just a string.

Now I want to give each `soil_unit_code` a number_id (1, 2, 3) in the new column: `soil_id`

In python it would look something like:

```
n=1
for i in soil_unit_code:
 soil_id = n
 n += 1
```

how would you do this with the Qgis field calculator?
I'm not looking for the @row_number. That would give each feature an ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
array_find (array_distinct (array_agg("soil_unit_code")), "soil_unit_code")
```

**Explanation:**

With `array_agg` (array aggregate), you get a list (array) of all values from the field `soil_unit_code`. `array_distinct` filters this to unique values. With `array_find`, you look for the position inside this array of unique values that the current value of the field `soil_unit_code` has: this is the output-value, used here as code.

[image]

Comment: If you find the time, @Babel, could you also explain what the different parts of the expression do? I find this very helpful usually, since it expands my knowledge of the field calculator, and especially arrays are rather tricky to work with.

Comment: @Erik - added that to my solution.